# Merging part of a repository into my repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a repository and I want to add the master branch from another repository to mine, so I did this:

```
git remote add upstream repo_link
git pull upstream master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Then I push to the origin and that's it.

Now, I want to keep it up to date, but without losing my changes, so I filter the files that I have created/modified, getting the author's email with this (and then doing some logic with python or bash)

```
git ls-tree -r main --name-only
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ae -- file_iterator
```

I pull from the other repository...

```
git pull upstream maaster -X theirs
```

Then, I reset my files that I got above checking the email, like this...

```
git reset origin/HEAD -- myfile_iterator
```

That works fine, but there is a big problem: `myfile`s have to be committed again, why? they are exactly the same files. I don't want to modify the history of `myfile`s, I want to leave `myfile`s untouched *always*.

As I understand it, `reset` downloads the file of the given commit in the given branch, repo, whatever, making it like an unmodified file, so I don't understand why it asks me to commit it again.

Is there a better approach to achieve this? basically what I want is to "freeze in time" those files that I have modified, everything else, pull from the external repository. I clarify that I just started with git, so probably there is a better way.

Comment: "*I want to keep it up to date, but without losing my changes*" You don't need to do anything fancy, that's what a merge is for. `git pull` is just a `git fetch` plus a `git merge`.

Comment: How you're doing it will be difficult to maintain, merging their unrelated code into yours. There's probably an easier method, but it depends on why you're pulling in unrelated code. How is their project related to yours?

Comment: I did that, and the merge had conflicts with all files, not just the external repository files.
If I use merge strategy option keep `ours`, It considers the previously pulled files as mine, not just the ones I edit, that's the problem, is there any strategy to get "ours" files but that they are *really* "ours" (aka created or modified by me)

But I can try again, maybe I did something wrong, what are the exact steps that I should follow?

Comment: The relationship is basically me modifying that project, I know I can do a fork or something like that, but I don't want to lose commit history, and I don't want to start a new repository either, due to "watchs", forks, etc. I originally made a new repository instead of a fork because I hardly knew anything about git

Comment: There's no "ours" or "yours" for whole files, only the changes to the files. All the merge cares about is whether each side changes the same lines. If you got conflicts, then both sides are working on the same lines. This has to be resolved by people, Git can't do it for you. Ignoring the conflicts will just break the code.

Comment: Then what would be the workaround to ensure that if there is a conflict, my file is kept? I know its not efficient, but I will not be updating the project too much really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The relationship is basically me modifying that project, I know I can do a fork or something like that, but I don't want to lose commit history, and I don't want to start a new repository either, due to "watchs", forks, etc. I originally made a new repository instead of a fork because I hardly knew anything about git*

You might think you're making it easier, but you're fighting Git and doing it the hard way. `git reset` and working with unrelated histories and fancy merges are all pretty advanced and entirely unnecessary for what you're doing.

> *Now, I want to keep it up to date, but without losing my changes, so I filter the files that I have created/modified...*

Changes often touch many files and need all those changes to work. Excluding their changes to any files you've touched is likely to break the code.

You don't need to do anything fancy, this is what merging is for. Merging your code with theirs will interlace their changes with yours. If you both change the same code you will get a conflict. Conflicts cannot Git cannot solve them for you. If you make them go away with --ours or --theirs you'll likely break the code. You must consider each conflict and how to resolve them.

None of this is necessary, this is what merges are for. `git pull` is just a `git fetch` and a `git merge`, so `git pull` should do the right thing.

---

Keep it simple. `git clone` the project. Make a branch. Do your work in that branch. When you want to update `git fetch` to get the latest version from the upstream project and then `git merge origin/master` to merge their work into your branch.

- `git fetch origin`
- `git merge origin/master`

(You can do this as a `git pull`, but while you're learning it's good to do the two steps to see what they do.)

Do all your work in a branch. Only `git pull` in master to keep your local version up to date. Isolating all your work from theirs is important.

Once you're comfortable with that, working with a Github fork is not much more complicated. [Github has good documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github), read through it. [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/) is also good.

On to the specific questions.

---

> *reset downloads the file of the given commit in the given branch, repo, whatever...

`git reset` is complicated. It does a lot of different things.

One thing to start with, `git reset` does not download anything. Git *never* talks to the network without your say so. The three basic network commands are `git fetch`, `git push`, and `git pull` (which does a `git fetch`). Everything else is local.

> *making it like an unmodified file so I don't understand why it asks me to commit it again.*

It is not unmodified. It's a bit of a mess.

> `git reset origin/HEAD -- myfile_iterator`

This only affects the staging area (stuff you `git add`). It does not change the working tree (the actual files) nor the commit. It's equivalent to the new `git restore --source origin/HEAD --staged myfile_iterator`.

You're left with the origin/HEAD version of myfile_iterator staged and your version of myfile_iterator on disk. If myfile_iterator in origin/HEAD is different from the version in your HEAD (ie. your last commit) it will show up as a staged change.

Using `git reset` requires a firm understanding of the working tree, staging area, HEAD, and commit history. Don't mess with it for now. Use `git restore` instead.

Note: `origin/HEAD` is not necessarily equivalent to `origin/master`. `origin/HEAD` can potentially be anything.

But all of this is unnecessary.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I should have clarified some things before:
1. my main goal is automate it, to use the repo in a gameserver and not have to worry about it being outdated.
2. I don't care about conflicts bc the files I modify are only config files, not code.
3. the only code i write is added in form of plugins, so they are new files, there will never be code conflicts, I'm sure of that.

Comment: what I did in the original post does almost what I want, the only thing I want is not to add to the commit the configs/plugins that have never been modified and mess those files history. The problem is that idk if thats possible.

Anyway, knowing what my goal is, what would be the proper way then? do it manually? what would you do in this case?.

again, there will be no code conflicts, and I want it to be automated

Comment: @Mis Git is not a configuration manager, nor a release tool, nor an installer, nor a dependency manager. Folks try to use it as one anyway. I would instead suggest keeping your plugins entirely separate. Write a little script which installs/updates the software then copies over your plugins; this script can use Git, just don't try to do it with only Git. Best would be to use a dependency manager for the project (which may use Git).

Comment: @Mis For example, Ruby has [Bundler to manage dependencies which can pull from Git repositories](https://bundler.io/v2.2/guides/git.html).

Comment: @Mis Even so, a simple branch of origin/master to work on your plugins will work fine. Nothing fancy, just keep it up to date with merges. There should be no conflicts, I expect those were an artifact of your complex process.